# Dragon Age Inquisition, how to start crafting?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Dragon Age Inquisition is the first title I play from the Dragon Age franchise, and since in the game I've gathered lots of materials I'd like to start crafting something but I cannot find how.

Have I to go back to the war table?

My character is at level 7, should that matter.

Comment: Is Skyhold available yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haven, the crafting stations are in the smithy, which you reach by turning left just after going through the main gate of the settlement (or just before? Not sure...). It's where Blackwall is found if you have recruited him.

In Skyhold, the crafting stations are in the Undercroft, which you reach via the door next to the throne. There's also crafting stations in some of the fortresses that you turn into camps in the other areas.